# Which is the best way to implement KNN in postgreSQL using a custom distance metric?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, distance, knn, gist

Let me explain my problem.
I have a table with this shape:

```
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| ID |  A   |     B     |     W     |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | 534  | [a,b,c]   | [4,6,2]   |
| 2  | 534  | [a,b,d,e] | [6,3,6,2] |
| …  | …    | …         | …         |
| 54 | 667  | [a,b,r,e] | [4,6,2,3] |
| 55 | 8789 | [d]       | [9]       |
| 56 | 8789 | [a,b,d]   | [7,2,3]   |
| 57 | 8789 | [d,e,f,g] | [4,2,2,8] |
| …  | …    | …         | …         |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
```

The query the I need to perform is the following: given an input with A,B and W values (e.g. A=8789; B=[a,b]; W=[3,2]) I need to find the "closest" line in the table that has the same value on A.

I've already defined my custom distance function.
The naive approach would be something like (given the input in the example):

```
SELECT * from my_table T, dist_function(T.B,T.W,ARRAY[a,b],ARRAY[3,2]) as dist 
WHERE T.A = 8789
ORDER BY dist ASC
LIMIT 7
```

In my understanding this is a classical KNN problem for which I realized something already exists:

- [KNN-GiST](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/wont-you-be-my-neighbor-quickly-finding-who-is-nearby)
- [GiST & SP-GiST](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-12-implementing-k-nearest-neighbor-space-partitioned-generalized-search-tree-indexes/)
- [SP-Gist example](https://github.com/fake-name/pg-spgist_hamming)

I'm just not sure about which is the best index to consider.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you would need to package B and W up into a single column (possibly using a functional index to do that dynamically)  to use KNN-GiST on them.  Also, your data does not seem to space-partitioning (but without seeing  the details of dist_function, who knows?) so spgist does not seem likely.

Comment: Let's say that dist_function is an Euclidean or something similar. So the column B represents the elements and the column W their weight or value. When dist_function is computed between two sets that have elements not in common, then those elements are added with W=0.
For example dist_function([a,b],[3,2],[a,b,d],[7,2,3]) is equal to dist_function([a,b,d],[3,2,0],[a,b,d],[7,2,3]).

Comment: I think you could do this (on a combined column), but not without writing an extensive amount of C code.  Also, I suspect it would not actually be very efficient, probably slower than the seq scan would be.  It would be hard to rule out entire branches of the tree when you have to dynamically decide which dimensions exist.

Comment: But the dist_function already takes care of what exists and what doesn't.
It's sound and it works among every pair of B,W.

Comment: It might be well defined at run time, but is still dynamic at index construction time, isn't it?  I guess you could say it is fixed at infinite dimensions, with almost all of them being zero.  But I don't see how that leads to any efficiency.  I could be wrong, but it just doesn't seem promising.

Comment: Let's just simplify the problem. What if I don't have the W column and my distance function is the simple size of intersection of the array in the B field? Would that change something?